# Texture flickering occurs when OpenGL renders .fbx or .dae files on the Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, fbx, 3d-model

Android uses OpenGL to render fbx or dae files, and the texture flickers. The situation is as follows.
How can I solve it?
PS：I set each vertex to be influenced by up to 8 bones

[This is png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpTTO.png)

[This is gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vl5JW.gif)

I expect to be able to find the cause of the problem and fix it

Following is the vertex shader：

```
#version 300 es
precision mediump float;

layout(location = 0) in vec3 a_position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 a_normal;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 a_texCoord;

layout(location = 3) in vec3 tangent;//
layout(location = 4) in vec3 bitangent;
layout(location = 5) in ivec4 boneIds;
layout(location = 6) in vec4 weights;
layout(location = 7) in ivec4 boneIds_plus;
layout(location = 8) in vec4 weights_plus;

uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;
uniform mat4 u_ModelMatrix;

const int MAX_BONES = 100;
const int MAX_BONE_INFLUENCE = 4;
uniform mat4 finalBonesMatrices[MAX_BONES];

out vec2 uv;
out vec3 fragPos;
out mat3 vary_tbnMatrix;
out vec3 normal;

void main() {
    uv = a_texCoord;
    vec4 position = vec4(0.0f);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < MAX_BONE_INFLUENCE ; i++)
    {
        if(boneIds[i] >= 0){
            vec4 localPosition = finalBonesMatrices[boneIds[i]] * vec4(a_position,1.0f);
            position += localPosition * weights[i];
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < MAX_BONE_INFLUENCE ; i++)
    {
        if(boneIds_plus[i] >= 0){
            vec4 localPosition = finalBonesMatrices[boneIds_plus[i]] * vec4(a_position,1.0f);
            position += localPosition * weights_plus[i];
        }
    }
    gl_Position = u_MVPMatrix * position;
    normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(u_ModelMatrix))) * a_normal;
    vec3 a_tangent = normalize(mat3(transpose(inverse(u_ModelMatrix))) * tangent);
    vec3 a_bitangent = normalize(mat3(transpose(inverse(u_ModelMatrix))) * bitangent);
    vary_tbnMatrix = mat3(a_tangent, a_bitangent, normal); 
    fragPos = vec3(u_ModelMatrix * position);
}
```

Following is the fragment shader

```
#version 300 es
precision mediump float;

out vec4 outColor;

in vec2 uv;
in vec3 normal;
in mat3 vary_tbnMatrix;
in vec3 fragPos;

uniform sampler2D texture_diffuse1;
uniform sampler2D texture_specular1;

uniform vec3 lightPos;
uniform vec3 lightColor;
uniform vec3 viewPos;

vec3 CalcDirLight(vec3 normal_world,vec3 viewDir)
{
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightPos - fragPos);
    vec3 diffuse = texture(texture_diffuse1,uv).rgb;
    float ambientStrength = 0.5;
    vec3 ambient_light = ambientStrength * diffuse * lightColor;
    float diffuseStrength = 0.5;
    float dif = max(dot(normal_world,lightDir),0.0);
    vec3 diffuse_light = diffuseStrength * dif * diffuse * lightColor;
    float specularStrength = 0.3;
    vec3 specular = texture(texture_specular1,uv).rgb;
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir,normal_world);
    float spec = pow(max(dot(normal_world,reflectDir),0.0),16.0);
    vec3 specular_light = specularStrength * spec * diffuse * lightColor;

    return (ambient_light + diffuse_light + specular_light);
}

void main() {
    vec3 normal_ = normalize(normal * 2.0 - 1.0);
    normal_ = normalize(vary_tbnMatrix * normal);

    vec3 worldNormal = normalize(normal_);
    vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPos - fragPos);
    vec3 result = CalcDirLight(worldNormal,viewDir);
    outColor = vec4(result,1.0);
}
```

Comment: From the gif, I would guess it's a depth issue of some sort. Check your depth write, depth test, depth buffer, depth range/resolution are all in order.

Comment: I have used “glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);”

Comment: Need a more complete reproducer. Looks like some form of geometry corruption or mesh sizing bug - you've got random triangles dropping, rather than specific pixels, so I don't think it's depth related.

Comment: Are all of the bones valid for every vert? Picking up an incorrect bone can flip facing.